# Difference of Squares (Factoring)

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I have no idea whatsoever how to factor out this:

$$ab^2 - a$$

I know how to solve $a^2 - 4$:
$$(a-2)(a+2)$$
But in that case, how can I factor out the $- a$ part?

Comment: Try$$ab^{2}-a=a\left(b^{2}-1\right)=a\left(b+1\right)\left(b-1\right).$$

Comment: Hint: transform it to a difference of squares either by pulling out a factor of $\,a,\,$ or, alternatively, by multiplying it by $\,a,\,$ then cancelling an $\,a\,$ at the end.

Comment: Note that the first step in factoring is to extract the common factor.  In this case, you extract $a$ to obtain $ab^2 - a = a(b^2 - 1)$, then factor the term inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can factor in two steps: $ab^2 - a = a(b^2 - 1)$ and then continue to factor $b^2 - 1$, which it seems you know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

$$ab^2 - a = a(b^2 - 1) = a(b-1)(b+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

In problem like these, always ask yourself this question "what do these terms have in common" once you can figure that out then take that common factor out. In this case $ab^2 - a$. both terms have $a$ in common so you take that has the common factor. $a(b^2-1)$ and now you know how to proceed about how to factor a binomial. basically $b^2=1$ then take square root of both side you have $b= 1$ or $-1$ so the final answer will be $a(b-1)(b+1)$. Hope that bring more clarity when come to factoring binomials.